# What does "resignation" mean in this extract?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "resignation" mean in the text below?

> There were many others who were alarmed by the drive to
> self-fulfillment Jane exhibited; The Spectator in April 1860 deplored
> the "pale, clever, and sharp-spoken young woman" who had become the
> fashion; the Saturday Review pretended **resignation** to the
> dominance of "glorified governesses in fiction," who, like the poor,
> would be always with them, since literature had "grown to be a woman's
> occupation."
>
> — [A Literature of Their Own by Elaine Showalter](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bkT_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=%22As%20Charlotte%20Bronte%20and%20George%20Eliot%20increasingly%20came%22&source=bl&ots=RqZ0skA88W&sig=ACfU3U3YbLQkSpIaEHWHdIVV0YonHH7oiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSwaCtr7TtAhXKjVkKHbx9BBkQ6AEwAnoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22As%20Charlotte%20Bronte%20and%20George%20Eliot%20increasingly%20came%22&f=false)

I looked it up in a few dictionaries, but I think none of them fits this context.

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/resignation#:%7E:text=1.,or%20office%3A%20submitted%20his%20resignation.), "resignation" means

> 1. The act or an instance of resigning
> 2. An oral or written statement that one is resigning a position or office
> 3. Unresisting acceptance of something as inescapable; submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's meaning No. 3. They pretended to be resigned to the fact that the spirited governess had become a favourite character in fiction.